# Retrieving Table cells value in Javascript - Firefox vs IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using the following code to retrieve the content of a cell in the table. This works fine in Mozilla Firefox. But, its not working in IE. Any suggestions??

```
var langName = tblCells[1].textContent.trim();
```

The error message is:

```
1.textContent is null or not an object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function text ( el ) {
   return el.textContent? el.textContent : el.innerText;
}
```

Use however you like. IE uses innerText.

Comment: Hi meder,
How should I call this function?
    Element el = tblCells[1];
    var langCode = text(el).trim();
I have tried this way. Its not working.

Comment: Pass the DOM element to it. `var theText = text( tblCells[1] );`

Comment: Hi Meder, its working now. I have one more question. I have tables with textboxes in the table cells. How could I retrieve the values of those textboxes? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the value attribute? you mean input?

Comment: I have tried it now. Its working fine. The code I use is:
var set2 = tblcells[3].firstChild.value.trim();

I have a query to you on commenting. How could I show code in codeblocks in comments?